# Earth Engine: Downgrading image resolution

Tags: google-earth-engine, resampling

I am trying to downgrade the resolution of high-resolution precipitation product (DayMet) to low resolution using the solution posted here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/323143/33177

However, I am getting the following error:

```
Layer error: Image.reduceResolution: The input to reduceResolution does not have a valid default projection. Use reproject() first to set the base projection.
```

I have checked both the images have default projection.
Here is the [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/638690dca10f8033c0ed242302f4c8d7)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to specify the scale when reprojecting.

```
var precipref_proj = precipref.reproject(dmProjection, null, 30).reduceResolution(...)
```